# Can't create bucket with domain name

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a verified domain from earlier but I can't see to create a bucket with that domain. How can I fix this.

[image: Error]

[[image: verified domain][1]]

Comment: I know this is a dumb guess, but have you verified the account you are using in GCP is the same which is the verified owner? Also, have you reviewed the troubleshooting steps over at the help page https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?visit_id=637473409170571549-2422331240&rd=1?

Comment: yeah its the same. I reverified it now again. Will check in sometime if I can create the bucket

Comment: but like I mentioned the problem is not with verification but with bucket creation after verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly reason, tere was a typo in the url :(. So @rsailnas was right